# Edit function not working after sort the data in angular js datatable

Tags: angularjs

I have a table on html page and this table have 15 records. each column have sorting functionality.
There is a edit button on each row to edit row value in separate tab, its working fine before sorting of data.

Means if you have clicked on table's column than edit function is not called.

```
 `<table id="tbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                                   datatable="ng" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Code</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Notes</th>
                                        <th>Description</th>
                                        <th style="text-align:center">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="e in entities">
                                        <td>{{e.name}}</td>
                                        <td>{{e.code}}</td>
                                        <td>{{getStatus(e.status)}}</td>
                                        <td>{{e.notes}}</td>
                                        <td>{{e.description}}</td>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <a href="" ng-click="edit(e)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" /></a>
                                            <span style="color: #ddd;">|</span>
                                            <a href="" ng-click="confimDelete(e)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" /></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

And controller code as below :

```
  $scope.edit = function (entity) {
    alert('name');
    $scope.entity = entity;
    $scope.activate('view');
};
```

This function named as edit called until we not click on header of data table.

please suggests what is issue.. thanks in advance

Comment: How the sorting is done?

Comment: we have no logic for sorting i have applied above directive for table tag and a java script files .

Comment: we are using the j query files for such type functionality. files is below : jquery.dataTables.js

Comment: we have use below files
     <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js">          </script>
    <script src="js/plugins/dataTables/js/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>`

Comment: This is not how it should be done in Angular, not surprisingly that you have problems. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background